# Prerequisites/Checks for performing clustering

Tags: clustering, k-means, unsupervised-learning, hierarchical-clustering

What are the checks that should be done on our data before performing clustering? Like how to check whether the dataset contains clusters of equal size/density or the clusters present in the dataset are spherical which are basically assumptions of K-means. I just wanted to know that just like in linear regression we have various checks like studying QQ plot to make sure the residuals are normally distributed, Are there any checks before performing a particular type of clustering.